Simplified bound on Gisin's "elegant" Bell inequalities?
The family of Bell inequalities obtained in https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0810.2937 (Gisin's study) on elegant Bell inequalities is well established. I was recently trying to work on simplifying the general form of one such "elegant" inequality. In this regard, I got stuck at the following stage where the following relation must hold:
\begin{equation}
n\binom{n-1}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor} = \sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}(n-2 r)\binom{n}{r}
\end{equation}
where, $\lfloor \quad \rfloor$ denotes the floor function and other symbols have their usual meanings. It is easy to see that numerically it holds good but I can't seem to find any analytical way to show it. Tried expanding the sum, too, but couldn't proceed much.
Any indication/hint/explicit proof in this regard is appreciated.

While the method in the linked question's answer appears sound, it should be noted that it uses $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ when it should be $\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$.

This question is similar to: Partial sums of binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^p\binom{n}{k} (n-2 k) = (p+1)\binom n{p+1}$, where both answers mention $n\binom{n-1}p = (p+1)\binom n{p+1}$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the indication!
